# How to reset or override a running async loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have an async function `foo` with an inner async `iterate` that has a loop. The loop awaits an inner promise to resolve before continuing. The outer async awaits `iterate` to finish before proceeding. I want to implement a reset button which restarts the loop.

Rerunning `iterate` in the handler, a new parallel running instance of the loop is made which can be run to completion. The issue is that `foo` is still waiting the first instance to complete. Is there a way to do this properly?

```
async function foo() {
  async function iterate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       const position = await new Promise() // Resolves after the user does something
       // do stuff
    }
  }

  button.onclick = async () => await iterate(); // Set up event handler

  await iterate(); // First call

  // Button gets clicked -> Second call takes over 
  // Now first call never ends and can't finish `foo()`

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*restarts the loop*"? Should it just reset `i = 0` so that the currently running loop starts over at the beginning? Or should it immediately start a new loop, and somehow cancel the currently running one? What should happen to `foo` that did start the loop in the first place? What should happen when the button is clicked while no loop is running (and `foo` already completed)? Lots of options, lots of edge cases to consider. We can't know what "properly" means in your concrete use case.

Comment: So the loop is meant for users to make decisions on each object in an array. At any point before completing, they should be able to  start over. My current approach is to start a new loop, but resetting `i = 0` would also work (maybe a while loop). `foo` in the end resolves and returns its own objects, but my issue was that I was stuck at first `await iterate()` call, Handling what happens when the button is cloiked after is a valid point and the listener should be removed at another milestone in `foo`. I used a promise based solution in my answer, but a while loop is interesting.

Comment: @Bergi Just tried a while loop with a counter, and that worked too.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it by using promises and more specifically, calling `resolve()`  after the loop, and more importantly, in the handler:

```
async function foo() {

  async function iterate() {
    await new Promise(async (resolve) => {

      button.onclick = async () => {
        await iterate(); // Set up event handler
        resolve();
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const position = await new Promise()
        // do stuff
      }
      resolve();
  }

  await iterate();
}
```

That way, even if initial loop never ends, when the call in the handler finishes, the handler itself calls `resolve()` and we exit this `foo`king mess.

This is only mildly hacky, but if someone has a more concise or direct approach, I'd be happy to check it out.